# How can I search for keys with part of the key name and put the information into variables in python?

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary, for-loop, key

ok, so I'm trying to do a program that searches for information on a CSV file and gives the user a list of the information that matches their search. The problem is the keys on the files are too long and specific, so I'm trying to get the program to search for keys that match the word given by the user and then print that in a neat format like:
product name: title
weblink: link
price: price

for each key that matches the word given by the user.

[picture of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EPGI.png)